# Open vSwitch bandwidth limit on VMs not working correctly

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to limit bandwidth on my VMs. I'm running KVM and my physical NIC is configured as an open vSwitch bridge. I have two Ubuntu VMs running and if I run iperf between them, I am getting around 7-8 Gb/s of throughput. But I'm trying to do a network benchmark and what I need is a maximum bandwidth set to, let's say, 1 Gb/s.
My ovs bridge has three interfaces - my physical interface and two vnet interfaces. I've ran these commands:

`$ ovs-vsctl set interface vnet0 ingress_policing_rate=1000000`

`$ ovs-vsctl set interface vnet0 ingress_policing_burst=100000`

as advised here: http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/qos/ .
The problem is, when I run iperf after these changes, I am getting only ~550 Mbits/s. Why is that? What can I change to get this close to 1 Gb/s? If it matters, device model in Virtual Network Interface in KVM is set to virtio.

Important note: if I set the limit to 1 Mb/s, I am only getting ~500 Kb/s. So there must be something wrong here.